# IOS build failed in Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, jenkins

yesterday my ios build started to fail, but i don't do anything, i try to checkout previous revisions because i think that code was broken but not. My build failed with the following output:

```
10:24:20 Code sign error: Failed to locate ResourceRules.plist in    '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/ResourceRules.plist' or '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/ResourceRules.plist'
10:24:20 [BEROR]error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk'
10:24:20 [BEROR]CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iPhoneOS 7.0'.    Your Xcode installation may be damaged.
10:24:20 
10:24:20 ** CLEAN FAILED **
10:24:20 
10:24:20 
10:24:20 The following build commands failed:
10:24:20    Check dependencies
10:24:20 (1 failure)
10:24:20 === BUILD TARGET fpg OF PROJECT fpg WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
10:24:20 
10:24:20 Check dependencies
10:24:20 Code sign error: Failed to locate ResourceRules.plist in '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/ResourceRules.plist' or '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/ResourceRules.plist'
10:24:20 error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk'
10:24:20 CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iPhoneOS 7.0'. Your  Xcode installation may be damaged.
10:24:20 
10:24:20 ** BUILD FAILED **
10:24:20 The following build commands failed:
10:24:20    Check dependencies
10:24:20 (1 failure)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to check your installed SDKs for Xcode?

```
xcodebuild -showsdks
```

You could also try `xcodebuild -list` in your current project to check your build configuration.